# How to convert string to any type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to convert a string to a generic type

I have this:

```
string inputValue = myTxtBox.Text;    

PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(myPropertyName);
Type propType = propInfo.PropertyType;

object propValue = ?????
```

I want to convert 'inputString' to the type of that property, to check if it's compatible
how can I do that?

tks

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
using System.ComponentModel;

TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propType);
object propValue = typeConverter.ConvertFromString(inputValue);
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this one gets the upvotes compared to `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: Probably because `ChangeType` tries to cast, not convert. For example, ChangeType can't go from `String` to `Nullable<Int64>` - `TypeConverter` can.

Comment: Nor can it handle automatic parsing of enums

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` also fails for string -> Guid

Answer (score 16):

Try [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28VS.100%29.aspx)

```
object propvalue = Convert.ChangeType(inputValue, propType);
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @SteveGuidi: Default already edited the answer in the meantime, tnx to both.

Comment: @SWeko it's the default reply when editing via the review page (and this question was there for both of us). I just edited it instead.

Comment: This is really the the proper way to do it.

Comment: I know there's another accept answer, but wanted to clarify why this is not: there's no way to convert a string to another type that's not a built-in value type using Convert.ChangeType().  This will use IConvertible.ToType() on the String type, which is implemented as calling internal method Convert.DefaultToType(), which throws an exception if the type to convert to is not a built-in value type. (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,dc591cb7008278c6)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think I understand what your are trying to archieve, but.. you mean a dynamic casting? Something like this:

```
 TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(String)).ConvertTo(myObject, typeof(Program));
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
string inputValue = myTxtBox.Text;    

PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(myPropertyName);
Type propType = propInfo.PropertyType;

propInfo.SetValue(myObject, Convert.ChangeType(inputValue, propType));
```

Here "myObject" is an instance of the class "MyClass", for which you want to set the property value generically.