# How to parse a string value to a custom type using a generic function

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, generics

I am trying to write a class to parse a XML config file with value strings to the corresponding values and type. An example entry of the config would be:

```
<ConfigItem Name="ParameterName" Value="1.3" Type="Double"/>
```

I now would like to write a function to parse my value, so that I can do something like this:

```
double value = GetItemValue("//ConfigItem[@Name='ParameterName']");
```

Initially I tried overloading `GetItemValue` with its return type, but this is not possible in C#. I now tried using a generic function so that I would do:

```
double value = GetItemValue<double>("//ConfigItem[@Name='ParameterName']");
```

The function I tried to write is something like this:

```
public T GetItemValue<T>(string configName)
{
    list = XmlConfig.SelectNodes(configName);

    T returnValue;
    if (T.TryParse(list[0].Attributes["Value"].Value, out returnValue))
        return returnValue;
    else
        throw new InvalidProgramException("Could not parse: " + configName);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I am getting the following error:

```
Error   CS0119  'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context
```

I am not sure what the problem is, but I suspect, it has to due with the fact, that it is not clear at compile time, whether all types `T` will have the method `TryParse`. I tried working around this by using a constraint like `where T : Int, Double`, but C# contraints do not support ValueTypes.

So what is the problem and how can I achieve, what I am trying to do? Please note for any suggestions that in the future I will also have to custom types for `T`.

Comment: If your're using [`int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your `T.TryParse()` method, you may have a bug.  `int.TryParse()` parses numbers *using the formatting information in a NumberFormatInfo object initialized for the current system culture.*  However, XML is conventionally culture-independent.  I'd recommend using culture-independent methods, or methods from [`XmlConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlConvert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Standard types.

Assuming that you only need standard built-in primitive types you can get away with [Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922855/how-to-convert-string-to-any-type) or something along that line.

#### Proper way with custom types.

But if you need to support custom types, then you can use [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). It is a bulky way, but, probably, the most correct. (Though to be honest I never fully tried it)

#### Simple custom solution.

If you don't want to mess with `TypeConverter`s, you can always use something like this, that just assumes a static `Parse(String)` method on your custom types:

```
public class Value
{
    private readonly Int32 _value;
    public Value(Int32 value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Value {0}", this._value);
    }

    public static Value Parse(String str)
    {
        return new Value(Int32.Parse(str));
    }
}


public class Converter
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<String, Object>> _parseFunctions;

    public Converter()
    {
        this._parseFunctions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<String, Object>>();
    }

    public T Convert<T>(String str)
    {
        Func<String, Object> parse;
        if (this._parseFunctions.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out parse))
        {
            return (T)parse(str);
        }

        var parseMethodInfo = typeof(T)
            .GetMethod(
                name: "Parse",
                bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                binder: null,
                types: new[] { typeof(String) },
                modifiers: null);

        if (parseMethodInfo != null)
        {
            var parameters = new [] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(String)) };
            parse = Expression
                .Lambda<Func<String, Object>>(
                    Expression.Convert(
                        expression: Expression.Call(null, parseMethodInfo, parameters),
                        type: typeof(Object)),
                    parameters: parameters)
                .Compile();
            this._parseFunctions.Add(typeof(T), parse);
            return (T)parse(str);
        }

        return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var converter = new Converter();
        Console.WriteLine(converter.Convert<Int32>("123"));
        Console.WriteLine(converter.Convert<Double>("123.32"));
        Console.WriteLine(converter.Convert<Value>("500"));
        Console.WriteLine(converter.Convert<Value>("600"));
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);         
}
```

Comment: He'll probably want to use [`TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hceyy41f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not [`ConvertFromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ds5cb6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to admit, I do not fully understand it (I am still new to C#), but I do like that it is lean. Unfortunately I have a problem with this solution, which likely has to do with my locale (german). The line `Console.WriteLine(converter.Convert<Double>("123.32"));` gives me the output `12332`. When I change it to `Console.WriteLine(converter.Convert<Double>("123,32"));` I get `123,32`. Is there a way to get your solution to work independently of the locale?

Comment: @packoman In such a case you can search for a `Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` instead of the `Parse(String)' method and use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as its second parameter `IFormatProvider`.