# C# convert string to Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm new to C#, and I'm trying to create a shape in PowerPoint from a given string that I receive from a JSON file.

This is the initial code that works well within **string[] arr_shape** and **new_slide** as a PowerPoint Slide:

```
var shape_width = float.Parse(arr_shape[1]);
var shape_postion_top = float.Parse(arr_shape[2]);
var shape_position_left = float.Parse(arr_shape[3]);
var shape_position_height = float.Parse(arr_shape[4]);

PowerPoint.Shape shape = new_slide.Shapes.AddShape(Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, shape_position_left, shape_postion_top, shape_width, shape_position_height);
```

So now I'm stuck trying to dynamically set the shape type from **string arr_shape[5]** that can contain any of the fields for [MsoAutoShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoautoshapetype).

I checked some of the solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922855/how-to-convert-string-to-any-type). I assume that the solution might be something like this:

```
Type shape_type = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Office.MsoAutoShapeType."+ arr_shape[5]);
PowerPoint.Shape shape = new_slide.Shapes.AddShape(shape_type, shape_position_left, shape_postion_top, shape_width, shape_position_height);
```

but it gives me the error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Type' to
> 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType'

I'd appreciate any help, because I'm stuck on this for over a week now...

Comment: You are trying to convert one type enumeration to another type enumeration that will not work. Core enumeration only accepts following values (which is different from the Type enumeration) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msoautoshapetype?force_isolation=true&view=office-pia

Comment: You could store in your array the enum value (like `1` for `msoShapeRectangle`) and [cast the int to the enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29482/205233).

Comment: Thanks for guiding me into this! [That really solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29482/205233)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem thanks for the guidance in the comments. I received enum shape type as a string from JSON and then [cast the int to the enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29482/205233) MsoAutoShapeType.

My solution looks like this now:

```
Office.MsoAutoShapeType shape_type = (Office.MsoAutoShapeType) Enum.Parse(typeof(Office.MsoAutoShapeType), arr_shape[7]);
PowerPoint.Shape shape = new_slide.Shapes.AddShape(shape_type, shape_position_left, shape_postion_top, shape_width, shape_position_height);
```