# How do I make a setter for any type of input value? (C#)

Tags: c#, setter

I have a property of type string. Any value must be placed in it: string-> string, number-> string, date> string with regional date display, boolean-> string with boolean representation. Do I need to create a function for each type? It turns out a lot of code, since the numeric types in C # are 10:

```
SetValue(int InputValue) {}
SetValue(uint InputValue) {}
SetValue(long InputValue) {}
SetValue(ulong InputValue) {}
```

Comment: "Do I need to create a function for each type?" - ideally, yes. How else will people know what types are actually accepted? (Any answer to my rhetorical question saying "check the documentation" is missing the point...)

Comment: Thanks for the orientation. I just started doing big programming, so I want to write correct (ideally) code from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

um... You don't need to create function for each type. Just use generic method.

To avoid boxing, not using object type is recommended.

you can write as follow.

```
    private void SetValueAsString<T>(T value)
    {
        // As Dai said, ToString() is not robust.
        StringProperty = value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to rely on `ToString()` then consider adding a constraint `where T : IConvertible`. However this still has _a bad code-smell_ about it...

Comment: Yes, i agree. ToString() is not robust.

I found another. See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922855/how-to-convert-string-to-any-type