# How to transforme Type to be a Int, float, bool or char struct in C#?

Tags: c#, types, code-generation, codegen

I am implementing a code generator in java that will create a C# code.
When I need to use Console.ReadLine() the variable have a type, but I don't know the type when I am generating the code.

So, is it possible to convert the type from Console.ReadLine() only with the variable?

Code example:

```
public static void main()
{
   var a = 1;
   var b = 2;

   /* The variable 'a' has a value and is of type integer, 
    * but when I generate this code I don't have this information */

   a = Console.ReadLine();


   /*I've tried to get type of variable but I didn't get success */
   var type = a.GetType();

   a = type.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), type);` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0#system-convert-changetype(system-object-system-type) | notice: return type of the method is object, would need to cast it to the desired type if object isn’t good enough

Comment: Or have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922855/how-to-convert-string-to-any-type

Comment: @RandRandom I've tried that tip and not sucess :(

Comment: Would need more information to help you further.

Comment: Read it as a string. Then use `int.TryParse` to see if it's an `int`. Failing, try `double.TryParse`, failing that, check if it's `true` or `false`, then check if it's a single character. That will tell you the type (and, for the `TryParse` calls give you the value). One you have the type, do a normal parse or conversion

Comment: @Flydog57 When I do that I get a compilation error, because in one of the cases I'm assigning a different type to the variable

Comment: I provided an answer below.  If you are returning possibly different types, you need to return the answer as an `object`.  I'm not quite sure what you are going to do with a value that can be one of many types (I've written programs like this before, but they tend to be reflection based and very complicated).  My solution below gives you both a value and a type.  You are on your own to figure out what to do with the result

Comment: "I don't know the type" - but if you generated `var a = 1;` you *do* know the type.

Comment: @KlausGütter My codegen is not prepared to get type when use arrays with N dimensions and struct :/ Because this I told that I didnt know the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this function `SetVariableValueFromInput`, I am able to convert a string to the type of a referenced object.

```
public static void @main()
{
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;

    SetVariableValueFromInput(ref a, Console.ReadLine());
}

static void SetVariableValueFromInput<T>(ref T myVariable, string myImput)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    myVariable = (T)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(myImput));
}
```

Comment: If you change your `SetVariableValueFromInput` function to return a `T`, (rather than using a `ref` parameter), you'll likely find your code easier to read. I still can't figure out this use case. You may also want to convert this to follow the `TrySomething` pattern; as written, it will throw an exception should your user enter a string that is not _convertible_

Answer (score 1):

How about a universal parser like this, it looks at the string and tries to see if it matches one of the types you list.  If there's a match, it returns the value and a `Type` (so that you can try to figure out what you've got).

```
public static (object value, Type type) ConvertToAnything(string input)
{
    if (int.TryParse(input, out var intResult))
    {
        return (intResult, typeof(int));
    }
    if (double.TryParse(input, out var doubleResult))
    {
        return (doubleResult, typeof(double));
    }
    if (input.Length == 1)
    {
        return (input[0], typeof(char));
    }
    if (input.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return (true, typeof(bool));
    }
    if (input.Equals("false", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return (false, typeof(bool));
    }
    return (input, typeof(string));
}
```

The `(object value, Type type)` return type says that the method returns a *Tuple* that pairs an `int` with a `Type`.

Here's some test code to see that it works:

```
var (result, type) = UniversalConverter.ConvertToAnything("123.4");
(result, type) = UniversalConverter.ConvertToAnything("false");
(result, type) = UniversalConverter.ConvertToAnything("123");
(result, type) = UniversalConverter.ConvertToAnything("a");
```

Comment: Instead of understanding the type of the input, I need to force the type of the input (make a convert) to the type of the variable, but I don't know the type of the variable, I just know that it exists and has a value. This code is generated by a code generator that I am implementing in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have assigned the value 1 to var a, there fore it is integer type. Now, while reading value from console, you have to Convert it into int.

```
public static void main()
{
   var a = 1;
   var b = 2;

   /* The variable 'a' has a value and is of type integer, 
    * but when I generate this code I don't have this information */

   a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Yes, but like I told, when I am generating the code I didn't know that variable 'a' is a integer to do the parse.